# Jupyter lab: Stop the loging messages printing out to cell output

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When I hit execute on a cell, especially when I start pyspark, the jupyter lab outputs the log messages to both my terminal & cell output as shown.
I do not want to see those big long messages to appear on jupyter output cell, when I can just see the same messages in the executing terminal (where I `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8088 --ip=0.0.0.0`.

TMIA,

BTW: I do not get this behavior on my personal machine, just on the EMR. So, this must be some config I missed.
Already tried:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

[image: Annoying EMR spark message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent log messages from being printed to cell output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731994/how-to-prevent-log-messages-from-being-printed-to-cell-output)