# How to prevent log messages from being printed to cell output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-logging

Importing [pygwalker](https://github.com/Kanaries/pygwalker) ([v0.1.11](https://pypi.org/project/pygwalker/0.1.11/)) changes what logging messages are displayed in the cell output. I can temporarily remove this import to prevent the messages from being logged, but I was wondering if there is an intended way to control the log messages displayed in Jupyter.

This example *does not* print the log message:

```
import logging
import numpy
import pandas

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("test")
```

This example (below) *does* print the log message:

```
import pygwalker
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("test")
```

Is there some way to programmatically determine the log messages that are printed in the cell output that can be performed regardless of the package imported?

#### What I've tried

- I have tried removing the import and this resolved the issue. However, I would like to be able to import this package AND control the log messages printed to the cell output.
- I have reported this as an issue on the GitHub repo for pygwalker.
- This question is related to [Jupyter lab: Stop the loging messages printing out to cell output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69574331/jupyter-lab-stop-the-loging-messages-printing-out-to-cell-output) but the imported package is different, and this one includes a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: When you use `getlogger`, you are asking to use whatever was the most recent logger to be configured.  If someone else did a configuration, you inherit it.  You should be able to use `logging.basicConfig` to set your own configuration.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for the quick response. I was under the impression that [`getLogger`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) with no arguments returned the root logger? Is this the same thing as the most recently configured logger?

Comment: Yes, but evidently pygwalker also did `getLogger()` and modified it.  You might try `logger.getLogger('main')` to create a new one just for you..

Comment: I see. However it seems that using a new logger with `logger.getLogger([some name])` still has a `StreamHandler` which results in the log messages being printed. I suppose the `pygwalker` package called `basicConfig` which is the root of the issue. I listed a few options for removing `StreamHandler`s from a logger in my answer.

Comment: I accepted my own answer for now but I am open to other ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in Jupyter Notebook can be configured by adding (or removing) [`logging.StreamHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) from a logger. Here are a few simple solutions to the issue in the question is the following:

#### Remove all `logging.StreamHandler` from the logger in question

```
logger.handlers = list(
    filter(
        lambda handler: not isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler), 
        logger.handlers
    )
)
```

#### Overwrite previous calls to `basicConfig`

```
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.NullHandler()], force=True)
```

This sets the default handler for any new loggers to be `logging.NullHandler()`. `force=True` is set because this call would be ignored if an imported package has already called `basicConfig`. A disadvantage with this approach is that it will become the default for *all* new loggers, so it lacks granular control.

#### Clear all previous handlers from the logger in use

```
logger.handlers.clear()
```

One potential disadvantage with this approach is if the logger in question had other important handlers configured, this would remove them entirely.